# How Softlayer API set OR condition in object filer

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

For example, I want ot GET `https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package/46/getItems.json` with some specified categories. I tried to use String contains filters in https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters, operation = '*= guest_core ram port_speed'.

```
Request URL:  GET https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package/46/getItems.json?objectFilter=%7B%22items%22%3A%7B%22categories%22%3A%7B%22categoryCode%22%3A%7B%22operation%22%3A%22%2A%3D+guest_core+ram+port_speed%22%7D%7D%7D%7D&objectMask=mask%5Bdescription%2C+capacity%2C+prices%5Bid%2C+locationGroupId%2C+categories%5BcategoryCode%5D%5D%5D
```

But it returned empty result.

Answer (score 0):

The objectFilter does not provide support for "OR" operation